# PHP for loop 'map' background color

Tags: php, html, dictionary, html-table

I've got a simple code that generates a 'map' or grid. im trying to define certain areas, in this example if the value for `$i` or `$j` is 1 then this defines the edge of my 'map' so I'm trying to set the class of that cell to 'edge' which is just a background color of grey for now.

```
echo "<tr>";

    for ($j=1; $j <= 50; $j++)

        {
        // edge of map - this is where i have a  problem
        if($i == '1' or $j == '1'){$st = 'class="edge"';}   

         echo "<td $st id = \"$i-$j\">";
         echo "$i-$j";
         echo "</td>";



        }

    echo "</tr>";
```

the problem is it turns all of the cells grey rather than just the cells which have a value of 1. I'm probably doing something stupid.

Comment: I would recommend comparing `$j` with `1` not `'1'`. Since `$j` is a number, there's no point in comparing it with a string.

Comment: It is because you're declaring `$st` as soon as the loop returns true. There's no reason for `$st` to become anything different after that.

Comment: Also, where are you declaring `$i`? I see you trying to compare it with 1, but you're not setting any value to `$i` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, always initialize, `$st = '';`. Then, if you want to shade all of the edges, of course you could hardcode `1` since it always start there and this will always be the edge. Check on both `i`  and `j`. Then on the other corner, just check the maximum size. In this example, its just `10`.

```
echo '<table>';
$size = 10;
for($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=1; $j <= $size; $j++) {
        // edge of map - this is where i have a  problem
        $st = '';
        if($i === 1 || $j === 1 || $i === $size || $j === $size){
            $st = 'class="edge"';
        }  

        echo "<td $st id = \"$i-$j\">";
        echo "$i-$j";
        echo "</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: @Mystic sure glad this shed some light